# OpenTelemetry + Jaeger tracing "Warnings: invalid parent span IDs=XXXX; skipping clock skew adjustment"

Tags: c#, asp.net, trace, open-telemetry, jaeger

I have two projects: Client and Server. I'm trying to do tracing to the Server using OpenTelemetry and JaegerUI.

I added this code to Program.cs in the Server project:

```
builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry()
    .WithTracing(trace =>
        trace.AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
        .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
        .AddSqlClientInstrumentation()
        .AddOtlpExporter());
```

Tracing is working, but not when sending a request from the Client. When sending a request using Postman or Windows Service, it worked, but when sending a request from Client, it did not work.
Then I added this code to the Program.cs in the Client project:

```
builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry().WithTracing(b => b.AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation());
```

Tracing has started to work, but traces HTTP requests sent from the Client contain "Warnings: invalid parent span IDs=XXXX; skipping clock skew adjustment". There is no warning when sending requests from other sources ().
Example of trace in JaegerUI:
[Example of trace in JaegerUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OK1l.png)
I assume that the reason is that the trace is first created in the Client, and not in the Server. Please help me fix this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.